# How do I get the UUID for a current logged in user?

Tags: 8

In the Drupal 8 user's table, there is a UUID field. I'm trying to figure out if there is some method to easily access the UUID for a current user like you would when you get a UID for a user.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load the UUID from entities with the method [uuid()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3Auuid/8.3.x). If you have an account from the current user service then you have to load the user entity first:

```
$account = User::load($account->id());
$uuid = $account->uuid();
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up with something similar just now:

```
  /** @var \Drupal\user\Entity\User $user */
  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
  $uuid = $user->uuid();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JSON:API, you can get the UUID of the currently logged in user from `/jsonapi`, which returns a "me" link in the "meta" info:

```
{
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "meta": {
      "links": {
        "self": {
        "href": "http://jsonapi.org/format/1.0/"
      }
    }
  }
},
"data": [],
"meta": {
  "links": {
    "me": {
      "meta": {
        "id": "7ab54c06-e431-41a7-8f1f-a7c2165114a2"
        },
        "href": "http://example.lndo.site/jsonapi/user/user/7ab54c06-e431-41a7-8f1f-a7c2165114a2"
      }
    }
  },
```

If you need to get the UUID of a specific user from JSON:API and you have the Drupal UID, you can do this:

```
https://example.com/jsonapi/user/user?filter[uid][value]=123
```

[Source](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi/issues/2927037#comment-12380894)